# Por que minha função está transformando algumas strings em caracteres separados ao enviá-las ao arquivo CSV?

Tags: python, csv

Criei a função a baixo para que gravasse as informações de um Json em um CSV. Porém ela grava o que está sendo apresentado no RESULTADO. Preciso que as informações fiquem uma ao lado da outra e que palavras não sejam separadas...

```
def create_csv(shop_name, access_token):
    with open('order.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        orders_list = request_products_shopify(shop_name, access_token)
        for order in orders_list['orders']:
            writer.writerow([order['id'], order['fulfillment_status'], order['cancelled_at'], order['cancel_reason'], order['total_discounts'], order['source_name'], order['total_tax'], order['email'], order['line_items'][0]['sku']])
            if len(order['discount_applications']) > 0:
                writer.writerow(order['discount_applications'][0]['type'])
            else:
                writer.writerow('none')
```

RESULTADO

```
0000000000000;;;;0.00;web;0.00;xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com;83630.S.EX1977
a;u;t;o;m;a;t;i;c
0000000000000;;;;0.00;web;0.00;xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com;43320.M.00PT01
n;o;n;e
0000000000000;;;;0.00;web;0.00;xxxxxxxxxxx@outlook.com;43383.S.00PT01
n;o;n;e
0000000000000;;;;0.00;web;0.00;xxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com;P3006.M.00PT01
a;u;t;o;m;a;t;i;c
0000000000000;;;;0.00;web;0.00;xxxxxxxxxxx@aol.com;83590.M.EX1968 
a;u;t;o;m;a;t;i;c
0000000000000;fulfilled;;;0.00;web;0.00;xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com;43355.S.00PT01
n;o;n;e
```

Como faço para que as informações fiquem da forma que eu preciso? Não entendo o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Tem como colocar um exemplo da entrada para poder testar a função?

Comment: Não posso... é confidencial. Desculpa

Comment: :) O dados não precisam ser verdadeiros, crie valores fictícios que sigam o formato dos dados reais. Ex: Onde tiver `nome:Juliana Nunes,cpf:65392210006` coloque `nome:Jurema Paliares,cpf:99990001111` e não precisam ser todos os dados basta umas três linhas para testes.

Comment: @hkotsubo Sim o resultado que eu gostaria é o de um campo adicional sem o ';' entre as letras.

Comment: @AugustoVasques entendi vou editar ela. é que o Json é gigante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [método `writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) recebe como parâmetro um objeto iterável e imprime cada elemento deste iterável como uma coluna separada. Como [strings são iteráveis](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), e ao iterar sobre uma string cada elemento é um dos seus caracteres, então ao passar uma string diretamente para `writerow`, cada caractere será considerado uma coluna. Para que toda a string seja considerada uma única coluna, ela deve estar dentro de um outro iterável (por exemplo, em uma lista). Ex:

```
import csv, sys
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=';')
writer.writerow('none') # passa a string diretamente
writer.writerow(['none']) # passa a string dentro de uma lista
```

Este código imprime o seguinte:

```
n;o;n;e
none
```

---

Só um detalhe: da maneira que você fez o código, a palavra "none" é colocada na linha de baixo, pois cada chamada de `writerow` cria um novo registro. Se era essa a intenção, então a solução acima (colocar o texto em uma lista) já resolve.

Mas se quer que o "none" faça parte do mesmo registro (ou seja, que ele não fique em uma linha separada), você deve primeiro criar a lista contendo todas as colunas e só no final escrevê-la no CSV:

```
for order in orders_list['orders']:
    # primeiro cria a lista com as colunas
    row = [order['id'], order['fulfillment_status'], order['cancelled_at'], order['cancel_reason'], order['total_discounts'], order['source_name'], order['total_tax'], order['email'], order['line_items'][0]['sku']]
    if len(order['discount_applications']) > 0:
        row.append(order['discount_applications'][0]['type'])
    else:
        row.append('none')

    # só no final escrevo o registro no CSV
    writer.writerow(row)
```